# Look for entries in json file and return values

Tags: python, json

I have a json that looks like this:

```
[

    {

        "annotations": {

            "__alertId__": "2846",

            "__alertImageToken__": "ac5bf4c7-9962-4d5c-8f36-4a72818c22fb",

            "__dashboardUid__": "veHIBjlGz",

            "__orgId__": "1",

            "__panelId__": "23",

            "__value_string__": "[ var='B0' metric='mem_used_percent' labels={__name__=mem_used_percent, application=xldeploy, env=xxx, host=host1, instance=host2.mycompany.local:9274, job=node, location=yours} value=59.19887041404578 ]",

            "__values__": "{\"B0\":59.19887041404578}",

            "message": "XxX memory usage high"

        },

        "endsAt": "2024-03-05T15:37:00.000+01:00",

        "fingerprint": "0085b140b3d18c9d",

        "generatorURL": https://grafana.mycompany.local/alerting/grafana/eb7e37c4-b1da-4836-a8b6-d47932df5fdf/view,

        "labels": {

            "__alert_rule_uid__": "eb7e37c4-b1da-4836-a8b6-d47932df5fdf",

            "__contacts__": "\"Yours Truly_1\"",

            "alertname": "XxX App memory alert ",

            "contacts": "Yours Truly_1",

            "grafana_folder": "MyFolder",

            "published_by": "pipeline",

            "rule_uid": "fb448adf-362e-4aaf-a65a-84224f3cd8a6",

            "version": "0.109"

        },

        "receivers": [

            {

                "active": null,

                "integrations": null,

                "name": "Yours truly_1 Teams Alerts"

            },

            {

                "active": null,

                "integrations": null,

                "name": "Your Truly_2 Teams Alerts "

            }

        ],

        "startsAt": "2024-03-05T11:25:00.000+01:00",

        "status": {

            "inhibitedBy": [],

            "silencedBy": [],

            "state": "active"

        },

        "updatedAt": "2024-03-05T15:33:00.789+01:00"

    },

    {

        "annotations": {

            "__dashboardUid__": "be61-46dasfasdf",

            "__orgId__": "1",

            "__panelId__": "167",

            "summary": "Something is gone wrong"

        },

        "endsAt": "2024-03-05T15:50:00.000+01:00",

        "fingerprint": "02c035fd70e67fd0",

        "generatorURL": https://grafana.mycompany.local/alerting/grafana/df946202-de59-43df-836e-c47a951283e5/view,

        "labels": {

            "__alert_rule_uid__": "df946202-de59-43df-836e-c47a951283e5",

            "__contacts__": "”yours truly_3"",

            "alertname": "DatasourceError",

            "contacts": "Some_processes",

            "grafana_folder": "MyFolder",

            "published_by": "pipeline",

            "rulename": "Number of Reps",

            "version": "0.34"

        },

        "receivers": [

            {

                "active": null,

                "integrations": null,

                "name": "Some_processes"

            }

        ],

        "startsAt": "2024-02-22T10:00:00.000+01:00",

        "status": {

            "inhibitedBy": [],

            "silencedBy": [],

            "state": "active"

        },

        "updatedAt": "2024-03-05T15:30:05.613+01:00"

    }

]
```

I am looking for pythonic way to search a dictionary based on specific entries, in this case i want to be able to match entries in "labels". So for instance when "__contacts____" == "Your Truly_1" and grafana_folder == Myfolder than myresult is true and want to return the  "alertname"

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: you should usually provide some code with your trials so far.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You may also find [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/) useful. Your data are not valid JSON

Comment: How does your current code fail? Note that your JSON is invalid, as pasted.

Comment: @Federicofkt You are right, my appologies

Comment: @CtrlZ Yes you are correct, altho i know this site is filled with great minds, which do not need my code to help me, but i ll add my code, which has seen alot of edits

Comment: @SiHa i have troubles understanding how to traverse a file with just dictionaries, when its a json with list, i am able to get my data. I do not have control over the contents of the file, this is pulled from grafana api(in this case i am getting all outstanding alerts, and shared a snippet of it

Comment: @Arch As the response from grafana is not valid JSON, you'll need to write your own parser that can build a Python dictionary from the data you receive. In particular, the value associated with generatorURL isn't quoted. Also, the value associated with \_\_contacts__ does not contain matching double quotes. Note that there's a right double quotation mark (\u201d) that either shouldn't be there at all or needs to matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `.get` should do the trick:

```
def search_labels(data, contacts, grafana_folder):
    for entry in data:
        if entry.get("labels"):
            if entry["labels"].get("__contacts__") == contacts and entry["labels"].get("grafana_folder") == grafana_folder:
                return entry["labels"].get("alertname")
    return None
```